# Xcode 8 Playground live view cannot interact with

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, uiswitch

I find my playground only can show the view of a control, I cannot press on it or interact with it.

The following picture is the running code and live view content.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are experiencing the same bug that is mentioned under https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/219665#219665 (appears in Xcode 8.3)

Comment: Thank you very much EricAya and JoRa. The workaround from link you mentioned works. And to EricAya, it is no need to set that variable when live view has been set a non-nil value. The following is said by documentation, "When liveView is set to a non-nil value the system sets needsIndefiniteExecution to true."

Comment: @Keith Good to know. Thanks for the feedback!